# Create pdf from html using Flying Saucer, renderer issue

Tags: android, rendering, flying-saucer

I'm trying to create a pdf using itext but i'm getting an error on the line :

```
ItextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
```

The error is something like this :

```
05-20 12:00:48.468: E/AndroidRuntime(6121): java.lang.VerifyError: org/xhtmlrenderer/pdf/ITextOutputDevice
```

It create the file but the file is a bug (the size is 0kb and it's not openable)

```
private void HTMLtoPDF(){
    try{
         String outputFile = "sdcard/firstdoc.pdf";
         OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

         ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
         renderer.setDocumentFromString(getHtmlBuffer().toString());
         renderer.layout();
         renderer.createPDF(os);
         renderer.finishPDF();
         os.close();
         }catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         }
}
private StringBuffer getHtmlBuffer() {
    StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
    buff.append("<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>");
    buff.append("<body>");
    buff.append("<h2 style='color: #353535;font-size: 16px;margin: 0px;padding: 20px 0px;font-weight: bold;'>Test</h2>");
    buff.append("<div id='news-details' class='news-details'>");
    buff.append("<div class='news-details-data'>");
    buff.append("some japanes charactors");
    buff.append("</div></div>");
    buff.append("</body></html>");
    return buff;
}
```

Comment: I am getting the same error. Any ideas how to make it work on Android?

Comment: @Tsunaze did you find any other libraries for android to convert html to pdf! how you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was also looking for an Android HTML to PDF converter and looked into Flying Saucer.  I ran into the same issue, and noticed that Flying Saucer is not an Android Library, but a **JAVA** Library.  It uses Java classes not available to Android (ex: java.awt.*), so the jar won't work on an Android device.

Comment: is there any other solution to convert html into pdf in android !?

Answer (score 1):

Format your HTML properly , i also had same issue ..
itext does not accepts unformatted HTML string, your pdf gets damaged..

Comment: I did change it to make something much easier, and it still gives me the same error.